# Prefilling login to paypal system

Tags: php, paypal

I`m using PayPal standard and buynow button. Exists any possibility how to pre-fill login e-mail into PayPal system after button submit? For example any hidden field, like "bussines"? This is helpfull in case, if i know users e-mail using as login to paypal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a hidden field called "email", but that's only used if the customer doesn't already have a PayPal account.  Otherwise, the email field will be prefilled with the customer's login info.

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_pdn_xclick_prepopulate_outside

Comment: I dont know, if I uderstand correctly to last sentence "Otherwise, the email field will be prefilled with the customer's login info.". You mean, that`s helpful only in case, if customer doesn`t have a paypal account, right? And prefilling of existing e-mail account is possible or not?

Comment: If they have a cookie from PayPal on their system from having logged in as bob@example.com, PayPal will ignore that parameter and prefill the login with bob@example.com instead of what you chose.

Comment: From what I understand, it only applies to people signing up for new accounts.

Comment: So if paypal account exists, it prefill login form, otherwise it prefill sing up form. Is it right?

Comment: Oukej, thank you. I would try it too, but i`m waiting for new bussines paypal account. I test it on sandbox to now... But Paypal changed access to sandbox through real account, which i dont have yet.